# Nasm and Disasm issue with 32/64 bit

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

I'm a nasm newbie and I wanted to compile this little snippet into 32 bit and 64 bit code:

```
pop bx
ret
```

get assembled to 0x5b 0xc3 with "nasm.exe asm.asm". This should be 32 bit code (nasm default) but "ndisasm.exe asm -b 32" incorrectly disassemble it to pop **ebx** and ret.

But

```
bits 64
pop bx
ret
```

gets assembled to 0x66 0x5b 0xc3 with "nasm.exe asm.asm" and "ndisasm.exe asm -b 64" correctly disassemble this to pop bx and ret.

Where am I getting wrong? I'm pretty confused right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the output format you use. If you don't specify an output format with `-f foo`, a default output format will be used, usually it's `bin`, and using `bin` as output format selects 16-bit mode, unless `BITS` is explicitly defined otherwise.

As it says [in the section 2.1.2 of NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.2): "**If you do not supply the `-f` option to NASM, it will choose an output file format for you itself. In the distribution versions of NASM, the default is always `bin`**; if you've compiled your own copy of NASM, you can redefine `OF_DEFAULT` at compile time and choose what you want the default to be."

So, assuming you haven't redefined `OF_DEFAULT`, nasm uses `bin` as output format by default.

Then, [in the section 7.1 of NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.1) it says the following: "The `bin` format does not produce object files: it generates nothing in the output file except the code you wrote. Such 'pure binary' files are used by MS-DOS: `.COM` executables and `.SYS` device drivers are pure binary files. Pure binary output is also useful for operating system and boot loader development."
...
"**Using the `bin` format puts NASM by default into 16-bit mode** (see section 6.1). In order to use `bin` to write 32-bit or 64-bit code, such as an OS kernel, you need to explicitly issue the `BITS 32` or `BITS 64` directive."

Then, as it says [in the section 6.1 of NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.1): "In most cases, you should not need to use `BITS` explicitly. **The `aout`, `coff`, `elf`, `macho`, `win32` and `win64` object formats, which are designed for use in 32-bit or 64-bit operating systems, all cause NASM to select 32-bit or 64-bit mode**, respectively, by default."

So, it all depends on the output format in use, unless `BITS` is explicitly defined.

Comment: Thank you for your work, I'm awarding the points to you since you spent time on this answer. Btw look at my answer that also solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I saw your answer but as it's not the whole truth (as usually one assembles to some object format, not a flat binary) and as I've been wondering with the 16/32/64 bits issue of NASM output myself too, I thought a more complete explanation could be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 4):

Terribly sorry to have posted this, but it seems that nasm defaults to 16 bit.

By using "bits 32" with the 32 bit code I solved everything.